# Error 91 variable not defined

Tags: excel, vba

This is the second day I've started with VBA.

I have this loop where I am first trying to match the value in column A sheet 1, and if this is true, it will go on to match the content in column B sheet 2:

```
For i = 1 To wsforecast.Cells(wsforecast.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 1 To wsregion26.Cells(wsregion26.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, "A").value = "AT" Then
        If Cells(i, "C").value = wsregion26.Cells(j, "B").value Then
        'rownr = j
        Let srange1 = "I" & j & ":" & "n" & j
        Range(srange1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("SP_FORECAST_macro.xlsm").Activate
        Let srange2 = "D" & i & ":" & "i" & i
        Range(srange2).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Transpose:=False
        End If
    End If
'Exit For
   Next j
    Next I
```

But I always get this error: "91" Object variable or with block variable not defined while I am pretty sure I have defined everything:

```
Dim wbforecast As Workbook, wbregion As Workbook
Dim wsforecast As Worksheet, wsregion10 As Worksheet, wsregion11 As Worksheet, wsregion26 As Worksheet

Set wbforecast = Workbooks("SP_FORECAST_macro.xlsm")
Set wsforecast = Workbooks("SP_FORECAST_macro.xlsm").Sheets("SP_FORECAST")
Set wbregion = Workbooks("Region.xlsm")
Set wsregion10 = Workbooks("Region.xlsm").Sheets("BE")
Set wsregion11 = Workbooks("Region.xlsm").Sheets("LU")
Set wsregion26 = Workbooks("Region.xlsm").Sheets("AT")
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, srange1, srange2 As Range
```

If you can help me learn what has caused this problem? Thank you guys very much!

Comment: What line do you get the error?

Comment: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html. Second day... so let's learn debugging first.

Comment: FYI the keyword `LET` is not required and hasn't been for many years.... Additional tips on debugging VBA: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `option explicit` at the top of your module to find variables you haven't defined.

```
Let srange1 = "I" & j & ":" & "n" & j
        Range(srange1).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("SP_FORECAST_macro.xlsm").Activate
        Let srange2 = "D" & i & ":" & "i" & i
        Range(srange2).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, Transpose:=False
```

can be simplified to

```
    srange1 = "I" & j & ":" & "n" & j
    srange2 = "D" & i & ":" & "i" & i
    wsforecast.Range(srange2).Value2 = wsregion26.Range(srange1).Value2
```

with

```
dim srange1 as string
dim srange2 as string
```

Comment: I was going to say `srange1`  is a range object, but it's not been declared properly so it's a `variant`.  `"I" & j & ":" & "n" & j` returns a string - something like `D3:i3`.  So your answer will work - I think `srange1` should be a range object from the start though.

Comment: yeah, I was looking at that thinking range or string. strRange or rngString. naming conventions! I went with strRange in the end because he then wrapped it in a range(str).Select

Comment: Aye. And this is why naming matters: `sourceAddress` would be completely unambiguous, compared to `srange1` which relies on Hungarian prefixes and tells nothing about how it's used.

Comment: Thank you it just worked when I changed the variable type from range to string for srange1 and 2. I really like the idea of the simplifying the code! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Let srange2 = "D" & i & ":" & "i" & i
```

should be

```
Set srange2 = Range("D" & i & ":" & "i" & i)
```

or

```
Set srange2 = Range(Cells(i, "D"), Cells(i, "I"))
```

or

```
Set srange2 = Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 9))
```

Note - in your code you're using `Cells` to identify a single cell.  You can also use it to identify the start and end cells within a range.

Comment: @Gareth no, it should be `Dim sRange1 as Range, sRange2 as Range`. VBA doesn't take implicit inline type declarations, multiple declarations without explicit type will always be `Variant` type.

Comment: I was referring to Poster's code. But I think it should be dim sRange1 as string anyway.. :)

Comment: Thank you Darren I do not have enough credit to give a thumbs-up!